# How can I redirect to another page using react vite?

Tags: reactjs, web, vite

I have a page in react called App.jsx, I want that when selecting a navar view it takes me to another one called patrocinio.jsx.
Attached code that I tried to do but the page appeared all blank

Try using the code from link to, and install the react-router-doom dependencies. I want it to allow me to navigate between pages

Answer (score -1):

To redirect to another page using React and Vite, you can use the useHistory hook from the react-router-dom library. Here's an example:

First, make sure you have installed react-router-dom by running npm install react-router-dom.

Then, import useHistory and Route from react-router-dom in the component where you want to redirect from:

```
import { useHistory, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

In your component, you can use the useHistory hook to get access to the history object, which you can use to navigate to another page:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push('/another-page');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go to another page</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the above example, the handleClick function is called when the button is clicked, and it uses the history.push() method to navigate to the /another-page route.

Alternatively, you can use the Route component to define the route you want to redirect to, and use the history.push() method to trigger the redirect:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push('/another-page');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go to another page</button>
      <Route path="/another-page">
        {/* Render the component or content for the other page here */}
      </Route>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this example, the Route component defines the /another-page route and the component or content to render when the route is accessed. The history.push() method is called in the handleClick function to trigger the redirect.